# Run rabbitMq in centos7 raise unable to connect to node rabbit@localhost: nodedown

Tags: rabbitmq

The rabbit service starts but will get an error by 'rabbitmqctl start_app'

attempted to contact: [rabbit@localhost]

rabbit@localhost:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on localhost
  * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
                  no other nodes on localhost
  * suggestion: start the node

current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-84@localhost'
- home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- cookie hash: Pz0CBhr6fjk9nLbhBwXlnA==

Answer (score 1):

I used https://gist.github.com/fernandoaleman/fe34e83781f222dfd8533b36a52dddcc to solve the issue, i uninstalled the rabbit and installed it again with the tips given by that link. i reckon the difference between the previous installation and this one was the: sudo firewall-cmd --reload